# model.bind and model.on: Are these methods equivalent? Which one should I prefer?

Tags: backbone.js

I did try the following in my `initialise` function in `Backbone.View`

```
this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
```

Apparently they work the same way.

Are this method equivalent.
Which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are equivalent. However, bind (and unbind) are only kept for backwards compability. You should use on.

Hope this helps!